# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1074, "Column length too big for column 'audio_file' (max = 16383); use BLOB or TEXT instead")

Tags: python, django

when I do python manage.py makemigrations it take the change but when I do python manage.py migrate it throw
error django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1074, "Column length too big for column 'audio_file' (max = 16383); use BLOB or TEXT instead")

I have models.py where my audio_file field is

```
class RadioFile(models.Model):    
    audio_file = models.FileField(
     upload_to='radio/',
     validators=[validate_file_extension],        
     max_length=200,
     help_text="Only wav,mp1,mp2,mp3,m4p,.m5p,wma,pdf and voc files are allowed.",
)
```

I tried to remove max_length completely from audio_file field,it is still giving me this error.
I check in other models.py , I don't have max_length set to max = 16383 anywhere neither field name audio_file.

from where this error is coming?

Comment: This error comes from the database, not the model. If the data you store in `audio_file` are the actual audio files, use BLOB data type. If you're only storing the path to the file, then reconsider your directory structure and filenames because paths shouldn't be more than 16383 characters.

Comment: I am just storing file name and to access file I am using MEDIA_ROOT and then file name stored in data base.

Comment: Have you removed the migrationsfile and re-run makemigrations after removing `max_length`? Django use 100 characters by default.

Comment: No, Not sure how to remove migrationsfile. can you please guide? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your file path does not exceed the 100 character limit, then you can skip it from your model definition. Django will use 100 characters by default: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield

Since the migration could not be performed, you can simply delete the generated file by the `makemigrations` command. You will find them in the migrations directory inside your app.
After that, just re run the makemigration command to generate a new migrations file without the `max_length` attribute.

For the sake of completeness: if the migration worked, you need to revert those changes first. You can check all migrations with `django-admin showmigrations`. If you need to revert by one migration (e.g. to 0003), then just put the number of the second last migration (marked with an X) to the following command `django-admin migrate [app_label] 003`. Then, remove the 0004 migration file and generate a new one.